# The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade, laravel-6

*Me genera este error al actualizar el producto, utilizo laravel 7.3, se lo de los navegadores no leen los metodos patch/put y le agregue al formulario la directiva @method y lo hice utilizando method_fields tambien pero me sigue generando el mismo error.*

**edit.blade.php**

```
@section('contenido')
            <div class="content-fluid">

                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <form action="{{ route('aluminio.store', $producto->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  @csrf
                  @method('PATCH')
                      <div class="col-10">
                          <h1 class="font-weight-bold my-3">Editar Producto</h1>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label  for="tipologia" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Tipología</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipologia" id="tipologia" value="{{ $producto->tipologia }}">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label  for="caracteristicas" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Características</label><br>                            
                          <textarea name="caracteristicas" id="caracteristicas" cols="42" rows="5">{{ $producto->caracteristicas }}</textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Actualizar</button>
                         </div>                       
                      </div>                       
                    </form>                 
                </div>
            </div>
            @endsection
```

**AluminioController.php**

```
public function edit($id){
        $producto = Aluminio::find($id);
        return view('aluminio.edit', compact('producto'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $producto = Aluminio::find($id);
        $producto-> tipologia = $request->tipologia;
        $producto-> caracteristicas = $request->caracteristicas;
        $producto-> ventajas = $request->ventajas;
        $producto-> desventajas = $request->desventajas;
        $producto-> foto = $request->foto;
        $producto-> nota = $request->nota;
        $producto->update();

        return redirect(route('aluminio'));
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('aluminio/{id}/edit', 'AluminioController@edit')->name('aluminio.edit');
Route::patch('aluminio/{id}', 'AluminioController@update')->name('aluminio.update');
```

Comment: Tu ruta con método patch se llama `aluminio.update` y no `aluminio.store` como lo tienes en el action del form `action="{{ route('aluminio.store', $producto->id) }}"`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error en tu form, la ruta que indicas es `route('aluminio.store', $producto->id)`.

Mientras que en tu **web.php** tienes `->name('aluminio.update');` la cual es una ruta diferente deberia bastar con cambiar tu form a el siguiente:

```
  <form action="{{ route('aluminio.update', $producto->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

el primer error esta acá
`action="{{ route('aluminio.**store**', $producto->id) }}"`

porque en el archivo de ruta web tiene el siguiente nombre `

```
Route::patch('aluminio/{id}', 'AluminioController@update')->name('aluminio.**update**');
```

en vez de

```
->name('aluminio.**store**');
```

y el segundo error es que los navegadores no soportan los metodos `PATCH`, cambia la ruta

```
Route::patch('aluminio/{id}', 'AluminioController@update')->name('aluminio.update');
```

por

```
Route::post('aluminio/{id}', 'AluminioController@update')->name('aluminio.store');
```

Comment: Trata de ser un poco mas descriptivo con la solucion al error, te recomiendo que leas  [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)